# Mongodb - convert map with dynamic fields to array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure in mongodb:

```
db.coll1.findOne({}, {myMap:1}):

{
  "x1-y1": {
    x: x1,
    y: y1,
    etc: ..
  },
  "x2-y2": {..}
}
```

where x and y are in range 0..100.

I think it was not a good idea to use dynamically named fields and I would like to convert this map into array:

```
db.coll1.findOne({}, {myArr:1}):

{[
  {
    x: x1,
    y: y1,
    etc: ..
  },
  { .. }
]}
```

I need no indexes on these fields. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using MongoDB 3.4.4 and newer:**

The **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator works well in this case but to get the desired results you would need to use it as an input expression for **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** and replace the `myMap` field with the results from **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** using **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)**.

Take for instance the following example:

**Populate test collection:**

```
db.test.insert({
    "myMap": {
        "0-1": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 1
        },
        "1-2": {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2
        }
    }
})
```

**Pipeline**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
       "myMap": {
           "$map": {
               "input": { "$objectToArray": "$myMap" },
               "as": "el",
               "in": "$$el.v"
           }
       } 
    } }
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba75f206346675838fec680"),
    "myMap" : [ 
        {
            "x" : 0.0,
            "y" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "x" : 1.0,
            "y" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

For older MongoDB versions which do not support the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator, the general idea is to loop through the collection, for each document map the subdocuments keys to a new array and update the document in with the field now storing an array. The intuition is best explained with an example and this assumes you have a few documents in the collection:

**Update**

```
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc){    
    var new_arr = Object.keys(doc.myMap).map(function(key){return doc.myMap[key]});    
    doc["myMap"] = new_arr;
    db.test.save(doc);
})
```

**Query**

```
db.test.find()
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bdae6ce3f9ad02c421e448"),
    "myMap" : [ 
        {
            "x" : 0,
            "y" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "x" : 1,
            "y" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

---

For a much larger collection, best leverage the updates with the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods)** API:

```
var ops = [];
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc){    
    var new_arr = Object.keys(doc.myMap).map(function(key){return doc.myMap[key]});    
    ops.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "myMap": new_arr } }
         }
    });
    if (ops.length == 1000) {
        db.test.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});         

if (ops.length > 0) { db.test.bulkWrite(ops); }
```

---

If your MongDB version does not support the bulkWrite API, use the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/)** methods available in versions 2.6 and 3.0:

```
var bulk = db.test.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    var new_arr = Object.keys(doc.myMap).map(function(key){return doc.myMap[key]});    
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "myMap": new_arr } 
    });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.test.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }    
});

if (counter % 1000 !== 0)
    bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have some troubles. After I execute "update" code I get: "myMap" : [ null, null ]. Also I don't have bulkUpdate(), maybe that's because mongo version is 2.6.11

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the bulk API applicable to your MongoDB version. Can you edit your question to add the actual document schema, perhaps the keys are not the same with the one in the code above?

Comment: The issue was in Object.keys ... return doc[key] -- should be return doc.myMap[key]. Would you please fix this typo in your answer? Many thanks for the answer!